# ScheduledExecutorService - After changing the value of frequency in the database, the code gets executed for the previous frequency also

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

The code below gets frequency from the database for running every particular hour(1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24) depending on a condition. When the frequency value is changed, the method runs for the previous frequency also. Why is it happening and how to prevent it from happening?

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Started.");
                ErrorReport errorReport = new ErrorReport();
                errorReport.eSchedule();
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    public void eSchedule() {
        try {
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            Class.forName(driverClassName);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUsername, dbPassword);

            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select reportName, frequency from ErrorReport where sendReport='Yes'");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {

                String reportName = rs.getString(1);
                String frequency = rs.getString(2);
                int freq = Integer.parseInt(frequency);

                ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(reportName + " " + freq);
                    }
                }, 0, freq, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

The output is like:

```
Started.
r1 1
r2 2
r1 1
r2 2
...
//When r2 is changed to 3
Started.
r2 2
r1 1
r1 1
r1 1
r2 3
...
r2 2
r1 1
r2 3
```

Comment: Every minute you schedule to schedule at fixed rate ... but you never cancel old schedules. Totally expected behavior.

Comment: May I know how the cancellation of the old schedules be done?

Comment: You need the future returned by schedule and then:`scheduledFuture.cancel(false);`

Comment: Okay, I'll try and see. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @Fildor Do you have any links about ScheduledFuture? The code is not working as expected. Only first two records are executed and the first scheduler gets called only once. I tried the following code. `private static ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(reportName + " " + freq);
                        ** scheduledFuture.cancel(false); **
                    }
                }, 0, freq, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`